# Row separator in datalist

Tags: asp.net, datalist

I'm using a datalist control. How I can add a row separator in the datalist?
I have more than one item in a row and I'm using .Net 2.0.

Separator template work for each item not for each row.
I want to display it like this.

```
row1-> item1 item2 
---separator
row2-> item3 item4
---separator
row3-> item5 item6
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
<asp:DataList>
    <SeparatorTemplate>
        <hr />
    </SeparatorTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

**Update**

If you want a simple border this way may help. the only problem is that latest row has a separator too.

```
<asp:DataList ID="DL1" runat="server" Width="200px" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatColumns="2" CssClass="DL1" CellPadding="0" CellSpacing="0">
    <ItemTemplate>
    .
    .
    .
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

---

```
.DL1 td
{
    border-bottom: solid 1px silver;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Comment: SeparatorTemplate is for each item not for rows (with multiple items).

Answer (score 0):

Formatting the DataList and Repeater Based Upon Data is explained with examples [here](http://www.asp.net/Learn/Data-Access/tutorial-30-cs.aspx),have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Use **DataList.SeparatorTemplate Property**

e.g.

```
<SeparatorTemplate>

        <asp:Image id="SeparatorImage"
             ImageUrl="SeparatorImage.jpg"
             runat="server"/>

     </SeparatorTemplate>
```

And look into this
[DataList.SeparatorTemplate Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist.separatortemplate(VS.71).aspx)